# Can datafactory start or stop self integration runtime?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a self integration runtime configured in a virtual machine on azure, because I need access on-premise database to load some information and this database can be accessed only throught VPN connection.

Is there a way to on/off the virtual machine when loading process is going to run (once a week) in order to optimize cost in the cloud ? because it not makes sense to me leave a vm billing at idle times.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

1. We can create Azure runbook, add PowerShell code to turn on/off the VM and call it in ADFv2 using Webhook according to this [post](https://www.mcconnellweb.com/posts/azure-startstop-vm/).
2. [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger). When creating a schedule trigger, you specify a schedule (start date, recurrence, end date etc.) for the trigger, and associate with a pipeline.
3. At the start  of the pipeline, you can use WebHook activity to start the vm, then copy data, at the end stop the vm. As follows:
   [image]

---

If you're looking to build data pipelines in Azure Data Factory, your cost will be split into two categories:

- Data Factory Operations
- Pipeline Orchestration and Execution

**Data Factory Operations**

- Read/Write: Every time you create/edit/delete a pipeline activity or a Data Factory entity such as a dataset, linked service, integration runtime or trigger, it counts towards your Data Factory Operations cost. These are billed at $0.50 per 50,000 operations.
- Monitoring: You can monitor each pipeline run and view the status for each individual activity. For each pipeline run, you can expect to retrieve one record for the pipeline and one record for each activity or trigger. For instance, you would be charged for 3 Monitoring activities if you debug a pipeline containing 2 activities. Monitoring activities are charged at $0.25 per 50,000 run records retrieved.

**Pipeline Orchestration**

- Self Hosted
  Every time you run a pipeline, you are charged for every activity and trigger inside that pipeline that is executed at a rate of $1.50 per 1000 Activity runs.

As an example, executing a pipeline with a trigger and two activities would be charged as 3 Activity runs.

**Pipeline Execution**

Self hosted
Data movement : $0.10/hour
Pipeline activities : $0.002/hour
External activities : $0.0001/hour

An `inactive pipeline` is charged at $0.80 per month.

**Summary**:
When there are 30 days in a month and if your pipeline starts to run on a certain day and continues to run for 10 hours to move data. It will charge according to `10hx$0.10/h = $1`. Pipelines that are inactive for an entire month are billed at the applicable "inactive pipeline" rate for the month as `29days/30days x $0.80 = $0.80`. So your total cost is `$1.8`.

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your answer, now from datafactory side is more clear for me the billing. but what about the virtual machine that I created to install adf agent (my self-hosted IR) ?, this virtual machine only will be use once a week beacuse the pipeline is configured to run with that scheduling. I suppose that azure not only is going to bill me datafactory as you explained, also, is going to bill me for the time the virtual machine is on. So, is another way to start and stop this virtual machine only when the pipeline is triggered ?. Regards

Comment: Hi @Joseph Xu, this last link can help me thank you, so I could call a runbook to start or stop de VM when needed, my doubt now is, if what's would the best way to start the VM. Because the idea would be to start it before run the pipeline and stop it after the pipeline ends, (this last I can achieve it adding a webhook activity that call the runbook to stop the VM). I suspect I need another service to orchestrate this, I mean, start vm -> call adf pipeline -> stop vm.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://sql.pawlikowski.pro/2018/07/01/en-azure-data-factory-v2-and-automation-running-pipeline-from-runbook-with-powershell/) would be a complement, sets runbook the responsability no only to start/stop the vm also to invoke the adf pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Carlos Villadiego, I've updated my answer. I think the easiest way is creating a trigger that runs a pipeline on a schedule.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Xu, this will be very useful and I think is a good approach.